# CGPoint question

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have two views: viewA ,viewB

I rotated and Zoomed viewA then I added viewB as subview on it then added gesture to viewB.

I want to get the location of the touch on viewB related to viewA, putting in consideration the rotation and the zooming

I tried

```
NSLog(@"Before teh conversion %f" , viewB.endPoint.x ) ; 

CGPoint aPtInScrollView = [viewB convertPoint:viewB.endPoint toView:viewA ]; 

NSLog(@"After teh conversion %f" , aPtInScrollView.x ) ;
```

Where endPoint is a point I save in it with the touch.

But it return the same point, and I want to see the effect of rotation and zooming, I mean the viewA location size, .. has been changed , so the point position should be changed

viewA , and viewB hs initial frame of [self.view frame]

Any suggestion to do that?

Comment: Does `viewB` take up the entire `viewA`'s bounds?

Comment: yes it is, have the same

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that `viewB` takes the entire bounds of `viewA`, it is the reason why you are getting the same point.

Say you have a `viewA` whose frame is (10, 10, 40, 40). And you add a subview whose frame is (0, 0, 40, 40) the a point (20, 20) in the subview will also be (20, 20) in `viewA`. You might want it in `viewA`'s superview's coordinate space where it will be (30, 30). For that you will need to do,

```
CGPoint aPtInScrollView = [viewB convertPoint:viewB.endPoint toView:viewA.superview];
```

Comment: will that put in consideration the rotation and the zooming factor of viewA

Comment: and what do u mean by viewA's superview's coordinate

Comment: Yes. As I understand your requirement, I think that should give you what you want. I could have misunderstood your question though. As for why we are using the `viewA`'s superview. The translation if any will show with respect to its superview. Inside `viewA`, everything will remain as it were.

Comment: viewA , and viewB hs initial frame of [self.view frame] , I tired ur code , but they are the same